# Compiling LLVM 2.9's gcc 4.2 on kernel 3.0 with gcc 4.6

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, linux-kernel, llvm, llvm-gcc

I'm trying to get [llvm-gcc 4.2.2.9](http://llvm.org/releases/download.html#2.9) to compile on this x86_64 system which runs the 3.0.0-21-generic kernel. llvm 2.9 itself builds fine. I suspected the downloadable version of llvm-gcc was causing some other problems, so I decided to build llvm-gcc myself.

Like suggested in the `README.LLVM` I configured with

```
../llvm-gcc-4.2-2.9.source/configure \
  --prefix=/opt/llvm-gcc4.2-2.9/../llvm-gcc4.2-2.9-install \
  --disable-multilib \
  --program-prefix=llvm- \
  --enable-llvm=/opt/llvm-2.9 \
  --host=x86_64-generic-linux-gnu
  --enable-languages=c,c++
```

I'm running this from the `/opt/llvm-gcc4.2-2.9` directory, while the sources are sitting in `/opt/llvm-gcc-4.2-2.9.source` and my llvm 2.9 lives in `/opt/llvm-2.9`. Note that I'm setting the `--host` instead of the `--target` as this implicitly sets the `--target` to the same architecture.

`make` does build a lot of stuff (producing a sizeable amount of warnings) when finally stopping at this error:

```
make[3]: Entering directory `/opt/llvm-gcc4.2-2.9/gcc'
/opt/llvm-gcc4.2-2.9/./gcc/xgcc -B/opt/llvm-gcc4.2-2.9/./gcc/ -B/opt/llvm-gcc4.2-2.9/../llvm-gcc4.2-2.9-install/x86_64-generic-linux-gnu/bin/ -B/opt/llvm-gcc4.2-2.9/../llvm-gcc4.2-2.9-install/x86_64-generic-linux-gnu/lib/ -isystem /opt/llvm-gcc4.2-2.9/../llvm-gcc4.2-2.9-install/x86_64-generic-linux-gnu/include -isystem /opt/llvm-gcc4.2-2.9/../llvm-gcc4.2-2.9-install/x86_64-generic-linux-gnu/sys-include  -O2 -O2 -g -O2  -DIN_GCC    -W -Wall -Wwrite-strings -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wold-style-definition  -isystem ./include  -I. -I. -I../../llvm-gcc-4.2-2.9.source/gcc -I../../llvm-gcc-4.2-2.9.source/gcc/. -I../../llvm-gcc-4.2-2.9.source/gcc/../include -I../../llvm-gcc-4.2-2.9.source/gcc/../libcpp/include  -I../../llvm-gcc-4.2-2.9.source/gcc/../libdecnumber -I../libdecnumber -I/opt/llvm-2.9/include  -g0 -finhibit-size-directive -fno-inline-functions -fno-exceptions -fno-zero-initialized-in-bss -fno-toplevel-reorder  -fno-omit-frame-pointer -fno-asynchronous-unwind-tables \
      -c ../../llvm-gcc-4.2-2.9.source/gcc/crtstuff.c -DCRT_BEGIN \
      -o crtbegin.o
In file included from /usr/include/stdio.h:28,
                 from ../../llvm-gcc-4.2-2.9.source/gcc/tsystem.h:90,
                 from ../../llvm-gcc-4.2-2.9.source/gcc/crtstuff.c:68:
/usr/include/features.h:323:26: error: bits/predefs.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/features.h:356:25: error: sys/cdefs.h: No such file or directory
/usr/include/features.h:388:23: error: gnu/stubs.h: No such file or directory
```

I find it a bit odd that the include path goes from my system's `stdio.h` back to `llvm-gcc` headers and then tries again to include system headers. But maybe that's normal?

After that error hundreds of lines with more errors follow *from the same compilation unit*.

Could it be that my system's gcc 4.6.1 or my system's headers maybe grew incompatible with the dated llvm-gcc 4.2 headers? Then again, I know that on a different system (running the 2.6 kernel) gcc 4.5.2 plays well with llvm 2.7's gcc 4.2.

I'm at a loss here, because I do need a recent llvm 2.*, and the other two acceptable llvm versions (2.7, 2.8) didn't show any result more helpful.

Comment: Maybe a stupid question, but did you try llvm-3.0 or llvm-3.1 with clang?

Comment: @honk: I didn't. Mainly for the reason that I woudn't have any use for llvm >= 3.0. I *need* llvm-gcc and llvm 2.9 (or 8 or 7).

Answer (score 0):

It seems that /usr/include on your system provides 32-bit headers, thus the compilation fails since you do not have all multilib headers installed. You might need to patch llvm-gcc the same way as your distribution patches gcc in order to find the headers locations.

Alternatively, you might try to install 32-bit headers and try multilib build of llvm-gcc.

But the best way will be switch to LLVM 3.1 and clang :)